Tengo un error de sintaxis en este codigo de php que lo estoy usando en un trigger para processmaker 3.2.3
Supuestamente es la linea 19 el signo igual pero no entiendo porque, la version de PHP es 5.6.37
@@selfServicePool = array($grupoPorteria);
PMFLog::debug('Grupo asignado: ' . $grupoPorteria);
PMFLog::debug('Valor de @@selfServicePool: ' . json_encode($ServicePool));


En un sitio pone @@selfServicePool y en el otro $ServicePool, ¿es eso correcto?

Según la doc, en el apartado Typing Rules for Case Variables debes usar la sintaxis @=variable_name para declarar arrays, booleanos u objetos, es decir, preceder la variable por @=, pero tú la estás precediendo por @@ que es para strings. Intenta así: @=selfServicePool = array($grupoPorteria);
